# Threaded upload with timeout in Python and PySide

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, multiprocessing, pyside

I am looking for a design pattern based on threading.Thread, multiprocessing or Queue to upload a list of items with a timeout. The thread allows the GUI to remain responsive. If the connection hangs, then the timeout should trigger and the program should gracefully exit.

The example below works, but the GUI remains blocked. How could this be improved to allow for uploading of the list, manual canceling of the process, timeout of the upload process plus a non-blocking GUI?

```html
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys
import time
import threading

class UploadWindow(QDialog):
 def __init__(self, parent=None):
  super(UploadWindow, self).__init__(parent)
  
  self.uploadBtn = QPushButton('Upload')
  mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
  mainLayout.addWidget(self.uploadBtn)
  self.uploadBtn.clicked.connect(self.do_upload)

  self.progressDialog = QProgressDialog(self)
  self.progressDialog.canceled.connect(self.cancelDownload)
  self.progressDialog.hide()
  
  self.setLayout(mainLayout)
  self.show()
  self.raise_()


 def do_upload(self):
  self.uploadBtn.setEnabled(False)
  self.progressDialog.setMaximum(10)
  self.progressDialog.show()
  self.upload_thread = UploadThread(self)
  self.upload_thread.start()
  self.upload_thread_stopped = False

  #List of items to upload
  for i in range(10):
   self.upload_thread = UploadThread(i)
   self.upload_thread.start()
   self.upload_thread.join(5)
   self.progressDialog.setValue(i)
   if self.upload_thread_stopped:
    break

  self.progressDialog.hide()
  self.uploadBtn.setEnabled(True)


 def cancelDownload(self):
  self.upload_thread_stopped = True


class UploadThread(threading.Thread):
 
 def __init__(self, i):
  super(UploadThread, self).__init__()
  self.i = i
  self.setDaemon(True)
  

 def run(self):
  time.sleep(0.25) #simulate upload time
  print self.i


if __name__ == '__main__':
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 w = UploadWindow()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The GUI is not responsive because you do all the work in `do_upload`, never going back to the main loop.

Also, you call `Thread.join()`, that blocks everything until the thread is done (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join)

You should use `PySide.QtCore.QThread` to take advantage of signals and slots.
Here is a [nice example in C++](https://fabienpn.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/qt-thread-simple-and-stable-with-sources/). I implemented it in Python3.4 with PyQt [here](https://github.com/tymoreau/simple-qt-thread), but you should be able to use it with PySide too.

You might also want to look at `PySide.QtCore.QProcess`, to avoid using threads.

Comment: Not a bad approach. But I fail to see how it handles the case of detecting when the upload hangs.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I put some code together that does what I think you want.

For a real project, be sure to keep track of what's uploaded better &/or use something safer than .terminate() to stop the thread on demand.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import time

class MySigObj(QtCore.QObject):
    strSig = QtCore.Signal(str)
    tupSig = QtCore.Signal(tuple)

class UploadThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UploadThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.endNow = False
        self.fileName = None
        self.sig = MySigObj()
        self.fileNames = []
        self.uploaded = []

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def setFileNames(self, t):
        self.fileNames = list(t)

    def run(self):
        while self.fileNames:
            print(self.fileNames)
            time.sleep(2)
            name = self.fileNames.pop(0)
            s = 'uploaded file: ' + name + '\n'
            print(s)
            self.sig.strSig.emit(s)
            self.uploaded.append(name)
            if len(self.fileNames) == 0:
                self.sig.strSig.emit("files transmitted: %s" % str(self.uploaded))
        else:
            time.sleep(1)   #if the thread started but no list, wait 1 sec every cycle thru
                            #that was this thread should release the Python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)


class ULoadWin(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ULoadWin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.upThread = UploadThread()
        self.sig = MySigObj()
        self.sig.tupSig.connect(self.upThread.setFileNames)
        self.upThread.sig.strSig.connect(self.txtMsgAppend)
        self.sig.tupSig.connect(self.upThread.setFileNames)
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.stButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        self.stButton.clicked.connect(self.uploadItems)
        self.stpButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Stop")
        self.stpButton.clicked.connect(self.killThread)
        self.testButton = QtGui.QPushButton("write txt\n not(?) blocked \nbelow")
        self.testButton.setMinimumHeight(28)
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.tstBlking)
        self.lbl = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.lbl.setMinimumHeight(325)
        self.lbl.setMinimumWidth(290)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.stButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.stpButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.testButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.l = ['a', 'list', 'of_files', 'we', 'will_pretend_to_upload', 'st', 'uploading']
        self.upThread.start()

    def tstBlking(self):
        self.lbl.append("txt not(?) blocked")

    def uploadItems(self):
        t = tuple(self.l)
        self.sig.tupSig.emit(t)
        self.upThread.start()

    def killThread(self):
        self.upThread.terminate()
        time.sleep(.01)
        self.upThread = UploadThread()

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def txtMsgAppend(self, txt):
        self.lbl.append(txt + "  |  ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widg=ULoadWin()
    widg.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. How does this solve the issue of detecting if the upload hangs?

Comment: Sorry about that - the current code doesn't implement the timeout feature yet. 
Check out http://www.matteomattei.com/pyside-signals-and-slots-with-qthread-example/ though. His code for an example QThread based app implements a timeout feature that works the same as what you need. He doesn't label it as a timeout anywhere, but check out how his class MyLongThread knows when to close. Good luck & sorry for the slow response

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved this problem by adapting the approach outlined [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/27/python-threads-communication-and-stopping), which I find to be an elegant solution. The class I created is shown below:

```python
class UploadThread(threading.Thread):

    #input_q and result_q are Queue.Queue objects
    def __init__(self, input_q, result_q):
        super(UploadThread, self).__init__()
        self.input_q = input_q
        self.result_q = result_q
        self.stoprequest = threading.Event() #threadsafe flag

    def run(self):
        '''Runs indefinitely until self.join() is called. 
        As soon as items are placed in the input_q, then the thread will process them until the input_q is emptied.
        '''
        while not self.stoprequest.isSet(): #stoprequest can be set from the main gui
            try:
                # Queue.get with timeout to allow checking self.stoprequest
                num = self.input_q.get(True, 0.1) #when the queue is empty it waits 100ms before raising the Queue.Empty error
                print 'In thread, processing', num
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.result_q.put(True) #Indicate to the main thread that an item was successfully processed.
            except Queue.Empty as e:
                continue

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.stoprequest.set()
        super(UploadThread, self).join(timeout)
```

In the main thread, the upload thread is created and the input_q is loaded with the items to upload. A QTimer is created to regularly check on the progress of the upload by checking what has been placed into the result_q. It also update the progress bar. If no progress has been made within a timeout, this indicates the upload connection has failed.

An advantage of using Queue.Queue objects for communicating between threads, is that multiple threads that share the same input and result queue can be created.